# Difference Between Source and Target DB using Python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to get row counts from two databases using Python 3, Oracle(source) and compare it against Snowflake(target) to check if there are any discrepancies in ETL. I need to write results of both and difference between them into a single file.

Here's what I've till now:

```
import cx_Oracle
import snowflake.connector
import sys
import csv
import os

exp_dir = os.path.normpath('C:/Users/user/Documents/')
exp_file_name = 'Count_Dff.csv'
exp_path = os.path.join(exp_dir, exp_file_name)

def runSQL(table):
    statement = "select '{0}', count(0) from  {0}".format(table.replace(' ',''))
    return statement


if __name__ == '__main__':
    """
    This function calls above functions and connects to Snowflake
    """
    tables = ['Table_1','Table_2']
    my_list = []
    try:
        conn_str = u'user/paswword@host/service'
        curcon = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str) 
        cursor = curcon.cursor()

        ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(user='****', password='****', account='****', role='***')
        cursor2 = ctx.cursor()
        cursor2.execute("USE WAREHOUSE ****")
        cursor2.execute("USE DATABASE ****")
        cursor2.execute("USE SCHEMA ****")

        for table in tables:
            my_dict = {}
            sql = runSQL(table)
            cursor.execute(sql)
            my_list.append(cursor)

        outputFile = open(exp_path,'w') # 'wb'
        output = csv.writer(outputFile)
        for data in my_list:
            output.writerow(data)


    finally:
        cursor.close()
        cursor2.close()
```

Clearly this is not a complete solution. I am bit lost on next step. Any input?

Expected Output:

```
|  Table_Name   |  Source_Count  | Target_Count | Difference  |  
|   Table1      |       14       |     12       |     2       |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not running the SQL command against the Snowflake database.  You probably should be doing something like this:

```
for table in tables:
    sql = runSQL(table)
    cursor.execute(sql)
    o_count = cursor.fetchone()[1]
    cursor2.execute(sql)
    s_count = cursor2.fetchone()[1]
    my_list.append([table, o_count, s_count, o_count - s_count])
```

**EDIT**
Added difference in response to comment.

Comment: yeah. I did not finish writing it since I am not sure how can I write results of both cursors for same tables on a same line. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Add a description of your desired output to your question.  The code snippet in my answer will put the counts from both cursors on the same line of the output.  It's not clear what else you're looking for.

Comment: Your code works. Problem I am having is its writing duplicate rows. I've edited my question with expected output. I also need difference between source and target

Comment: If your list of table (in `tables`) is unique, how are you getting duplicate rows in the output?  To get the differences in row counts, just calculate it from the returned values, as in the edited answer.

Comment: nevermind. My bad, both tables I was looking at had same row counts, so got confused.I am trying to create column name but this part isn't working: ```with open(exp_path,'w') as outputFile:
 output = csv.DictWriter(outputFile, fieldnames=['TABLE','SOURCE','TARGET','DIFFERENCE'])
 output.writeheader()``` The error says: can't find '__main__' module in ''

Comment: Using the code that you originally posted, just do `output.writerow(['TABLE','SOURCE','TARGET','DIFFERENCE'])` before processing the tables.